# "Control Center" like sliding view controller

Tags: ios, swift, interactive, transition

I'm trying to create an interactive sliding transition between two View Controllers.

The goal is to have a main view controller, and a secondary view controller that will be dragged from the bottom(not from the bottom edge so it won't conflict with the control center) and will partially cover the main view controller (just like the iOS control center).
The transition should be interactive, i.e according to the dragging of the user.

Would be happy to hear ideas regarding available APIs.

[image: Control center in ios]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any success @Rgo with this.? i'm also looking for something like this.

Comment: @YashBedi eventually I wrote it myself, but I saw this library a while ago:

Comment: https://github.com/HarshilShah/DeckTransition

Comment: Thank mate. cheers

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use [UIViewControllerTransitionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/). It has [interactionControllerForPresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate/interactionControllerForPresentation:) to which you can give speed of transition and curve.